# Pull image with docker-compose run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's a typical docker-compose file. I use is it both for building image (**docker-compose build**) and to run my tests (**docker-compose run test** ).

```
    version: '2'
    services:

      test : 
        links: 
         - web

        cmd : "mvn clean verify"

      web: 
        image: my_repo/my_image:tag
        build: .
```

When I use the **run** command docker-compose try to build the image before running the test.

Is there anyway to force it to pull existing image instead of trying to build new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal that it's build the **web** image before creating the **test** container, because there's link between (**web** depends on **test**). If you want to not do the build each time you run **docker-compose up**, start by creating your **web** image:

```
docker build -t web .
```

then update your Dockerfile with the new image:

```
version: '2'
    services:

      test : 
        links: 
         - web

        cmd : "mvn clean verify"

      web: 
        image: web
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "pull" command before run. There is pull all new images from registry

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose run
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your solutions work fine.

I was just expecting to have to have some thing like

'**docker run test --pull**' or '**docker dun test --build**' to force the pull/build.

Thanks !